# Select and Delete multiple rows by selecting checkboxes using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

Delete multiple rows by selecting checkboxes using PHP

Hi iam working on select and delete multiple rows from database  using below code problem is iam having problem with php script

```
 <input class='file'  type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="hid" id="<?php $rs["carimgid"]; ?>" placeholder="Please choose your image">
```

this my ajax script where using this to delete multiple row without refresh

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#master').on('click', function(e) {
        if($(this).is(':checked',true))  
        {
            $(".sub_chk").prop('checked', true);  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            $(".sub_chk").prop('checked',false);  
        }  
    });
    jQuery('.delete_all').on('click', function(e) { 
        var allVals = [];  
        $(".sub_chk:checked").each(function() {  
            allVals.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
        });  
        //alert(allVals.length); return false;  
        if(allVals.length <=0)  
        {  
            alert("Please select row.");  
        }  
        else {  
            //$("#loading").show(); 
            WRN_PROFILE_DELETE = "Are you sure you want to delete this row?";  
            var check = confirm(WRN_PROFILE_DELETE);  
            if(check == true){  
                //for server side

                var join_selected_values = allVals.join(","); 

                $.ajax({   

                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "delete.php",  
                    cache:false,  
                    data: 'ids='+join_selected_values,  
                    success: function(response)  
                    {   
                        $("#loading").hide();  
                        $("#msgdiv").html(response);
                        //referesh table
                    }   
                });
              //for client side
              $.each(allVals, function( index, value ) {
                  $('table tr').filter("[data-row-id='" + value + "']").remove();
              });


            }  
        }  
    });
    jQuery('.remove-row').on('click', function(e) {
        WRN_PROFILE_DELETE = "Are you sure you want to delete this row?";  
            var check = confirm(WRN_PROFILE_DELETE);  
            if(check == true){
                $('table tr').filter("[data-row-id='" + $(this).attr('data-id') + "']").remove();
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

and my php code is

```
<?php
  include("config.php");
   if(isset($_POST['ids'])){


 $result=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM carimg WHERE carimgid ='$id'");
   }
?>
```

Delete multiple rows by selecting checkboxes using PHP

Hi iam working on select and delete multiple rows from database  using below code problem is iam having problem with php script

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read through [ask]. All you told us is you have a problem but not which part of the code is causing the problem or any troubleshooting details that would help us help you with whatever the speicif problem is. there are multiple layers here... user events...client side ajax request and server side request handling. Narrow down what does or doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You haven't got the ids from POST. 
Look at the following

```
$ids = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ids']);
if(!empty($ids)){
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM carimg WHERE carimgid IN ({$ids})");
}
```